# How do I mount a Codespace's workspace in a Docker container?

Tags: docker, codespaces

When I try to mount the workspace directory in a Codespace in a Docker container (with `-v`), the mounted path is empty, e.g:

```
$ ls /workspaces/myrepo
[list of files]

$ docker run -it --rm -v /workspaces/myrepo:/app alpine:latest

/ # ls /app
[nothing]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *believe* this is because the Codespace is itself running in Docker, and so the mount points are relative to the Docker host (of the Codespace), not to the container in which the Codespace is running.

---

One solution is to use `--volumes-from` to remount the volumes for the Codespace (e.g. `/workspaces/myrepo`) **inside** the container you are starting. This requires knowing the container ID of the container in which the Codespace is running, which we can obtain with `docker ps --filter "label=Type=codespaces"`.

As a bonus `--workdir` can also be used to start the container in the current directory.

Putting it together:

```
$ docker run -it --rm --volumes-from $(docker ps --filter "label=Type=codespaces" -q) --workdir $(pwd) alpine:latest

/workspaces/myrepo/ # ls .
[list of files]
```